# Azure pipelines and yaml: How to address files several folders down?

Tags: node.js, build, yaml, azure-pipelines, package.json

I'm building my first Azure pipelines for a Node project and I'm wondering how in Yaml to access several package.json files below the surface level of the project?

How can I run this?

```
- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

On files below the surface?

Alternatively, I was considering having multiple Yaml files all at the same level as the node projects I'm trying to build, and using a master yaml to trigger all the child yamls.

If I'm just doing this completely wrong, please don't hesitate to correct me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like you normally would in the console?

```
- script: |
    cd some\folder\with\code
    npm ci
    npm run build
```

> Alternatively, I was considering having multiple Yaml files all at the same level as the node projects I'm trying to build, and using a master yaml to trigger all the child yamls.

i dont think it works this way ;)